# Wie spricht man eigentlich „eigentlich“ aus?

Tags: pronunciation

Im alltäglichen Gespräch hört man öfters tatsächlich eine kürzere, geschmierte Version der ersten zwei Silben von *eigentlich.* Kann jemand anhand IPA diese Aussprache beschreiben?

Comment: Meinst du, wenn aus "g" ein "j" wird?

Comment: Es könnte sich um regionale Varianten (wo?) handeln. Hier in Schwaben würde man es so aussprechen: `[ˈaɪ̯ɡɛndlɪç]`. Die hochdeutsche Aussprache soll `[ˈaɪ̯ɡn̩tlɪç]` sein.

Comment: Vielleicht kann jemand sich [seine Stimme aufnehmen](http://forvo.com/word/eigentlich/#de), damit c.p. beide die Aufnahme und IPA Aussprache hat, und für andere IPA nicht verstehen.

Comment: Das Verschlucken des [ɛ] hört sich für mich entweder nach schlampiger Sprache oder nach Schnupfen an. Ich spreche das Wort so, dass man die Silben noch deutlich auseinanderhalten kann.

Comment: tofro, sprichst du da wirklich einen Vok., oder willst du hauptsächl. darauf hinaus, dass das Wort bei dir dreisilbig ist? Denn das ist die von Takkat zitierte stddt. Ausspr. [ˈaɪ̯ɡn̩tlɪç] (so ähnlich, wohl mit [ŋ] anstelle [n], spreche ich das Wort in deutlicherer Sprache) nämlich auch. Das Diakritikum unter dem *n* zeigt an, dass [n] einen dritten Silbenkern darstellt (neben den den Vok. [aɪ̯] und [ɪ]) und es somit drei Silben gibt. In "standardnaher" Sprache würde ich nicht erwarten, dass jemand dort [ɛ] verwendet, allerhöchstens [ə], aber das dann auch schon eher als (Aachener?) Ausnahme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich kann *eigentlich* bis auf etwa ['aeŋtlɪç] "reduzieren", wenn ich schnell spreche. Bei der Notation des Diphthongs bin ich mir nicht ganz sicher, aber ein [ɪ] ist das abschließende Element des Diphthongs bei einer solchen (schnellen) Aussprache bei mir sicher nicht mehr.

Geographisch bin ich im Westen Deutschlands anzusiedeln.

Comment: Mit /t/? Bei mir und anderen Norddeutschen klingt es eher wie _einklich_.

Comment: Ich kann mir gut vorstellen, dass Leute das so aussprechen, aber ich glaube, ich mache das nicht. Es kommt mir jedenfalls komisch vor, wenn ich versuche, _eigentlich_ so auszusprechen.